# Swift String Conditional Error

Tags: arrays, swift, debugging, button, conditional-statements

In my checkers project, I am trying to find the selected tile by finding the i and j positions that correspond to the title of the pressed button.

My problem is that the code keeps on failing in the conditions I set. It simply iterates through the entire array without finding the match.

My question is two fold. A) Am I making a basic error or is this method simply unworkable? B) If this is some basic error what is the fix, and if it is unworkable is there another method I could try?

Note: I have not yet updated to Xcode 3

[Here is an example read-out of what happens, I clicked on the button in the upper left hand corner of the checkerboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19Z0K.png)

The code I wrote is as follows:

View Controller Page (relevant portion, and is within the viewcontroller class):

```
func placeButtons(){
    for i in 0..<(Int)(boardWidth){
    var column: [UIButton] = []
        for j in 0..<(Int)(boardHeight){ //make sure only place on 8x8 board
            let tileRect = CGRect(x: 40+(40*i), y: 60+(40*j), width: 40, height: 40)
            let button = UIButton(frame: tileRect) //place a button in the Rect
            button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal) //Name button for cordinates on array
            button.titleLabel?.text = ("\(i), \(j)") //see above
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside) //link button to action
            view.addSubview(button) //put button on screen
            column.append(button) //add button to array
        }
    field.append(column) //add column of buttons to array
    }
}

func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!){
    selectedTile = "\(sender.titleLabel?.text)"
    print("got here-1")
    print("\(selectedTile)")
    selectFunction()
    /*if sender.titleLabel?.text != nil{
        saysTurn.text = "\(sender.titleLabel)"
        print("\(sender.titleLabel)")
    } else{

    } */ //works, get the actual play code up. Maybe click the first button for select checker to move, and the second select is where to move the checker to?
}
```

Rules Page:

```
import Foundation

var piecePlacement = [[Int]](count: 8, repeatedValue: [Int](count: 8, repeatedValue: 0))
var selectedPiece: String = ""
var selectedMove: String = ""
var teamRequired: String = ""
var tester: String? = ""


func selectFunction(){ //something is failing in the selectedPiece    conditionals. Also, maybe switch from String to CGPoint to make it easier   to edit arrays? (and avoid having to constaly iterate over the entire array?)
    if  turnCounter % 2 == 0{
        teamRequired = "black"
    } else{
        teamRequired = "red"
    }
    print("got here-2")
    for i in 0..<(Int)(boardWidth){
        for j in 0..<(Int)(boardHeight){
            tester = "\(i), \(j)"
            print("\(tester)")
            if selectedTile == tester && ((piecePlacement[i][j] == 1 || piecePlacement[i][j] == 2)) && teamRequired == "black"{
                selectedPiece = selectedTile
                print ("\(selectedPiece)")
                print("\(i), \(j)")
                print("done-1")
            } else if selectedTile == tester && ((piecePlacement[i][j] == 3 || piecePlacement[i][j] == 4)) && teamRequired == "red"{
                selectedPiece = selectedTile
                print ("\(selectedPiece)")
                print("done-2")
            } else if selectedMove == "" && selectedTile == tester{
                selectedMove = selectedTile
                print ("\(selectedMove)")
                print("I Printed selectedMove \(i), \(j)")
            } else{
                print("got here-3")
            }
        }
    }
    if isLegalMove() == true{
        //func move
        print("move")
    }else{

    }
    print("end")
}

func isLegalMove() -> Bool{
    //if touched point is either x+1 && y+1 or x+1 && y-1 (if red, x-1 if black)  of the original checker's point, or if the checker is a king and the touched point is either x+/-1 && y+/-1. And the touched position is within the bounds of the board, the move is legal.
    return true 
}
```

Comment: It's Swift 3 / Xcode 8... not Xcode 3.

Comment: selectedTile seems to contain (Optional), not just (0,0), so it will not match tester?

Comment: selectedTile does not seem to match tester, even though both read as "Optional("0, 0")" in the read out.                                                                        The read-out between "got here-1" and "got here-2" is selectedTile, while the one between "got here-2" and "got here-3" is tester.